# How to convert function call to string with inputs evaluated first?

Tags: javascript, string, function

```
var width = 10;
var height = 5;
drawBox(width,heigh);
```

Wanted result:

```
'drawBox(10,5);'  <-- a string, not the returned value
```

Although `'drawBox(' + width + ',' + height + ');'` works, this is far too ugly, plus I have many inputs but not two.

Is there any smart function dedicated to this problem?

Comment: _"this is far too ugly"_ - The fact that you "need" it as a string at all seems pretty ugly to me. What are you actually trying to do here? Why do you want strings?

Comment: College assignment, which needs to return the called function in string, not something I want to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (http://jsfiddle.net/L2JJc/1/)?

```
var createStrFunction = function(name, paramArray){
    return name + "(" + paramArray.join(",") + ");";
}

createStrFunction("drawBox", [5,10]);
```

Comment: It is something I want. So there is no existent function similar to this available? something like toString that converts a number to string?

Comment: No, I don't think so. What are you trying to do? nnnnnn is right in saying that needing strings is bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can augment `Function`'s prototype with the new property, something like this:

```
Function.prototype.callAndGetSR = function() {
    this.call(this, arguments); 
    return this.name + '(' + Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(', ') + ')';
}
```

(*SR* stands for String Representation).
Call it like this:

```
drawBox.callAndGetSR(5,10);
```

This call draws the box and returns function name with arguments used, i.e. `drawBox(5, 10)`. This new property assumes that you don't return anything from your `drawBox` function.

If you need to return something from `drawBox` function and get the string representation of function with its parameters, you can write it to the log:

```
Function.prototype.callAndGetSR = function() {
    console.log(this.name + '(' + Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(', ') + ')');
    this.call(this, arguments); 
}
drawBox.callAndGetSR(5,10); // writes drawBox(5, 10) to log first, after that invokes the drawBox function
```

Or you can simplify new property and make it return string representation w/o calling the function:

```
Function.prototype.getSR = function() {
    return this.name + '(' + Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(', ') + ')';
}
drawBox.getSR(5,10); // returns drawBox(5, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity:

```
function funcToString(func, params) {
    return func.name + "("
               + [].slice.call(arguments, 1).slice(0, func.length).join(",")
           + ")";
}
```

Call it as follows:

```
function foo(a, b) { /* ... */ };
var width = 10, height = 20;

funcToString(foo, width, height); // returns "foo(10,20)"
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/iGasIGem/1/)